# Unit Tests: how to prevent execution of built-in PHP functions

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd

I'm doing a small library that uses native PHP methods, like `json_encode` and `file_put_contents`.

Now, I'm doing unit testing, and `json_encode` doesn't bother me if it runs, but `file_put_contents` creates me files when running unit tests.

What ideas do you have about this?

I was thinking of encapsulating these methods in Helpers, eg. JsonHelper, FileHelper, with methods that execute these, and mock them in the original class.

What do you think?

Comment: https://medium.com/weebly-engineering/phpunit-mocking-the-file-system-using-vfsstream-5d7d79b1eb2a

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulating functions that are external dependencies is a good idea in general. In PHP I would usually have classes like `JsonEncoder`, `File` and `Calendar` (the latter for encapsulating date functions). Please do not call them `XyzHelper`. A baby bunny dies everytime people name classes like that.